# How to make an active element?

Tags: angular

How to make an active first item if no other item has been selected?

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let rep4Hour of rep4Hours">
    <a  class="{{selectedRep4Hour == rep4Hour ? 'active' : ''}} list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" (click)="onSelectedRep4Hours(rep4Hour.hour_id)">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-2 h5">{{rep4Hour.report_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h5>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: `*ngFor="let rep4Hour of rep4Hours, let first = first"` and then add this `[class.active]="first"`

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor exposes a few variables you can see [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/).

The one we are interested in is `first`:

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let rep4Hour of rep4Hours; let first = first">
    <a [class.active]="yourConditionsToBeSelected(first)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" (click)="onSelectedRep4Hours(rep4Hour.hour_id)">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-2 h5">{{rep4Hour.report_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h5>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that `yourConditionsToBeSelected()` is a placeholder method you should create with whatever conditions you have (like "no other element is selected", or "is this element selected", or "`selectedRep4Hour == rep4Hour`" whatever that means) and receives a boolean that states if it's the first element or not.

Any further question just let me know and I will clarify